# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below.
Clicking on Edit works, clicking on delete fails on

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#modal"));`
```

saying

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined"

As I googled it, the solution of this error should be to order javascript includes in proper order, but they are already in correct order I think, and if they weren't, edit would fail as well

```
<script>

    $('.Edit').click(function () {
        //...

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Client/Edit/?id=" + userId,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modal').html(data);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#modal"));
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });

    $('.Delete').click(function () {
        //...

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Client/_Delete/?id=" + userId,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modal').html(data);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#modal"));
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

the generated file includes these in the following order:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
...
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is validator?

Comment: if you include plugins correctly,make sure you don't have jquery conflicts

Comment: We need to see the part of code where you include the javascript files

Comment: Your `<script>` inclusion should be `<script src="/your_script_path/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` followed by `<script src="/your_script_path/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @DavidR your suggestion worked for me. thanks :)

Comment: @Jawand Singh Glad that it helped!  